# Is there an equivalent to NoSuchKeyException in AWS SDK for PHP v3?

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

AWS SDK v2 used to have a specific [NoSuchKeyException](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.S3.Exception.NoSuchKeyException.html), which is gone in v3.

This was the way then to catch a non-existing key error:

```php
try {
    $s3Client->getObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $key
    ]);
} catch (NoSuchKeyException $e) {
    // ...
}
```

The only exception thrown now is [S3Exception](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/class-Aws.S3.Exception.S3Exception.html), which does not have a similar sub-class.

**How can I know, when catching S3Exception, if the exception relates to a non-existing key?**

Is there a specific exception code, and if so, where to find the list of such codes?

Comment: Try it with a non-existing key and see what error code is thrown with `getAwsErrorCode()` then you'll just have to hard-code the error code to identify that particular issue.

Comment: @fire Yes, just found this out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found the reason in the [migration guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/migration.html#fine-grained-exception-classes-have-been-removed):

> You should handle errors by catching the root exception class for each
>   service (e.g., Aws\Rds\Exception\RdsException). You can use the
>   getAwsErrorCode() method of the exception to check for specific error
>   codes. This is functionally equivalent to catching different exception
>   classes, but provides that function without adding bloat to the SDK.

And the [list of error codes for S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html), which shows that the one I'm looking for is `NoSuchKey`.

So the new way to catch this error is:

```
try {
    $s3Client->getObject([
        'Bucket' => $bucket,
        'Key'    => $key
    ]);
} catch (S3Exception $e) {
    if ($e->getAwsErrorCode() == 'NoSuchKey') {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work when using the `SaveAs` param. I opened a github issue for it: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1355

Comment: Using AWS SDK v2 I was getting: `NoSuchKeyException`. With `v3` I am getting `S3Exception` where `getAwsErrorCode()` equals to: `NotFound`